# Limit of a recurrence series

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, difference-equations

I am beginner with Mathematica and I am trying to find the limit of a recurrence series.
This is my series: `u[n+1] = 1/2*(u[n] + a / u[n])` with `u[0] > 0`
After a few experimentation I tried this :

```
u[x_] := 1/2*(u[n - 1] + 9/u[n - 1]); u[0] = 10;
lim = SequenceLimit[N[Table[u[n], {n, 1, 100}], 50]
```

But nothing's happen! I try to understand better this function I found on the internet, but I can't find in the actual Wolfram Documentation.
The result should be: sqrt(a) (3 in the case where a = 9)

Every help and advice for a beginner like me will be helpful.

Comment: Try `u[n_] := ...`.  Also, what is `SequenceLimit`?

Comment: It's a function I found on the internet and it works with other examples...

Comment: I've seen this error when I copied here : u[x_], but it doesn't work with u[n_] as well. :(

Comment: @bb, see [this](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/834).

Answer (score 2):

Using [`RSolve`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RSolve.html) for the case `u0 > Sqrt[a] > 0`

```
Assuming[{u0 > Sqrt[a] > 0},
 Limit[u[n] /. RSolve[
      {u[n] == 1/2*(u[n - 1] + a/u[n - 1]), u[0] == u0},
      u[n], n][[1]], n -> Infinity] // Quiet]

(*  Sqrt[a]  *)
```

For the specific case of of `a=9` then the [`Limit`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Limit.html) is `3`

Answer (score 1):

```
Use RSolve:
In[1]:= un=u[n]/.RSolve[{u[n]==1/2*(u[n-1]+9/u[n-1]),u[0]==10},u[n],n][[1]]
During evaluation of In[1]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
Out[1]= 3 Coth[2^n ArcCoth[10/3]]
In[2]:= Limit[un,n->Infinity]
Out[2]= 3
```

The series can be solved symbolically, but for the limit we likely need a value for a:

```
In[3]:= un=u[n]/.RSolve[{u[n]==1/2*(u[n-1]+a/u[n-1]),u[0]==u0},u[n],n][[1]]
During evaluation of In[3]:= Solve::ifun: Inverse functions are being used by Solve, so some solutions may not be found; use Reduce for complete solution information.
Out[3]= Sqrt[a] Coth[2^n ArcCoth[u0/Sqrt[a]]]
```

Comment: It works! Thanks!

Comment: Thanks for adding the symbolic solution, it helps to understand bette RSolve.

Answer (score 1):

Any steady state solution (limiting value) to this problem will occur at a value ustar where `ustar == 1/2*(ustar + a/ustar)`. This is easy to find:

```
Solve[ustar == 1/2*(ustar + a/ustar), ustar]
{{ustar -> -Sqrt[a]}, {ustar -> Sqrt[a]}}
```

Answer (score 1):

For your particular example of a = 9 you could have written it like this:

```
s = RecurrenceTable[{u[n] == 1/2*(u[n - 1] + 9/u[n - 1]), u[0] == 10},u, {n, 0, 10}];

SequenceLimit[s]

(*3.000000000000000*)
```

Pretty suggestive!

Comment: Thanks, it works. I would like to know more about this function and I don't find in the actual documentation...

Comment: First try ?SequenceLimit  and then look here http://compgroups.net/comp.soft-sys.math.mathematica/limit-of-list/904787